# UITableView crash gives 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [160 nan]'

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a custom table view in my app. I have implemented the "Load More" feature to the table which loads 25 rows at a time. The problem is after loading 2 times the app crashes giving 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [160 nan]' as error on OS 4.2 and above.

On OS below 4.2 one of the cell goes missing and there is blank space between in the middle of the table. It do not give any crash. But it still gives the error mentioned above.

I check to see where can the division by 0 can occur in my code but i couldnt find any. Following the stack trace i fond. So i cannot even check where this exception is happening.

Anybody have any idea ??

```
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x020ccbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x022215c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x02085628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0208559a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
 4   QuartzCore                          0x0182396a _ZL18CALayerSetPositionP7CALayerRKN2CA4Vec2IdEEb + 177
 5   QuartzCore                          0x018238b5 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 42
 6   QuartzCore                          0x018237cc -[CALayer setFrame:] + 763
 7   UIKit                               0x0073c307 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 255
 8   UIKit                               0x008c718a -[UITableViewCell setFrame:] + 166
 9   UIKit                               0x0077aa08 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 1160
 10  UIKit                               0x0077077f -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
 11  UIKit                               0x00785450 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
 12  UIKit                               0x0077d538 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
 13  QuartzCore                          0x01828451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
 14  QuartzCore                          0x0182817c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
 15  QuartzCore                          0x0182137c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
 16  QuartzCore                          0x018210d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
 17  QuartzCore                          0x018517d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
 18  CoreFoundation                      0x020adfbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
 19  CoreFoundation                      0x020430e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
 20  CoreFoundation                      0x0200bbd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
 21  CoreFoundation                      0x0200b240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
 22  CoreFoundation                      0x0200b161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
 23  GraphicsServices                    0x02611268 GSEventRunModal + 217
 24  GraphicsServices                    0x0261132d GSEventRun + 115
 25  UIKit                               0x0071542e UIApplicationMain + 1160
```

Comment: Whats weird is that this error happens only on the 43rd row of the table. Rest all the rows display fine.

Comment: This problem is making me lose sooooo much sleep, anyone got any good ideas?

Comment: We need to look at the code to help you.

Comment: Please provide the loadMore code.  I do that in my app without any problem.

Answer (score 28):

I had this same exact error because instead of writing

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ... }
```

i wrote:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { ... }
```

(notice the return value).
Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: I have wasted my whole day.. Now finally solved the problem..
Thanks @Moszi

Comment: Thanks! This saved me too! If only I saw this earlier!

Comment: Fascinating. How come that at least 24 people use a wrong type for the return value of a callback method?

Answer (score 21):

The stack trace looks like the UITableView is busy layouting the visible cells when the exception occurs. Since the position of a cell seems to be set to a `NaN` value one has to ask how this can happen.

Assuming there's no bug in the UITableView layout code, the only way this can happen is that you implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view delegate and return a bad height (or one of the according header or footer methods).

**Edit** to pinpoint the exact cause of the exception:

I assume you calculated the height of the cell from the geometric size of a string (using `UIStringDrawing`'s `-[NSString sizeWithFont:]`). When you send a message to a nil value, the return value usually is nil, 0, NO, or whatever value is represented by an all-bits-zero word.

For a method that returns a struct (as `sizeWithFont:`) this is not true. The returned struct is not initialized at all, containing random values for its elements.

In your case, you probably used one of the uninitialized elements of the CGSize struct, which later turned out not to be a valid IEEE 754 floating point value.

**Addendum:** Since clang 3.0 the structs returned from messages are initialized to {0} (all bits zero). So above problem should not happen any more.

Comment: I do implement the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: to return custom row heights, but i'm not sure how it can return a bad height? Can u elaborate on that?

Comment: your right that it has to do with the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method, i commented this out and it works fine now and doesn't crash.  But for my app I need to be able to dynamically change the row heights to fit the content.  You got any suggestions to how I can do this and return a good value so it doesn't crash?

Comment: ok cool i got it, turns out i wasn't checking for a null string which was screwing up the height thanks, i'll award u bounty when it lets me in 3 hours

Comment: I am not dynamically setting the row height of the table in my code. I have defined the row height when the view loads by  setting tableView.rowHeight. So i dont know where is this problem occuring. I also checked if i am getting any null strings. But nope all the strings are correct. This crash happens randomly. For sometime it will work but other times it wont and it always happens at the same row.

Comment: Does it happen on the device or simulator or both? Do you use any other geometric overrides (like `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` or `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`)? Can you post the project?

Comment: No i am not using any of those methods. I can send you the sample code which is a part of my application. But i cannot send it working because of the users privacy issues. You can go through the code though. Here is the link to the code:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13284881/Sample_Code.zip                                                 I also saw that you edited the post stating font size as one of the reason. I also commented out the place where i set the font size but still same.

Comment: Same happened to me whilst configuring UISlider   //  playlistSlider.frame = CGRectMake(20, 920,width , 60);
 when I commented it out, it stopped..

Answer (score 5):

[Messages to nil that return structs of structs can return undefined values in the inner struct.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7)

In practical terms, this means that getting the `frame` from a `nil` `UIView` can return undefined values in the `size` field of the `frame`.  This bug just bit me and I was surprised.

Answer (score 2):

**The simple answer:**

Returning a NaN from any of the height related delegate methods causes this error.

```
 tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
 tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:
 tableView:heightForFooterInSection:
```

etc..

There may be other ways to produce this error but if you're working with UITableView--check this first!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was caused by the toView in this code being nil:

```
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.fromView
                        toView:self.toView
                      duration:0.6
                       options:(currentPage > toPage ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown : UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp)
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        if (finished) {
                        }
                    }
```